# How can you report or display an error from an XSP.partialRefreshPost call

Tags: xpages

I am using custom event handlers for many parts of our application.  Tim Tripcony describes this [in his blog](http://www.timtripcony.com/blog.nsf/d6plinks/TTRY-84B6VP)... He will, most likely (hopefully) answer this...

The event handlers in my code look like this:

```
    <xp:eventHandler
        id="newbsDoSomething"
        submit="true"
        event="calledbyid"
        refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action>
            <![CDATA[#{javascript:doSomethingFromSomewhere();}]]>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
```

The buttons or other controls execute these events with code that look like this:

```
XSP.partialRefreshPost(("#{id:newbsDoSomething}", {
    params : {
        '$$xspsubmitvalue' : 'something that tells it what to do.'
    },
    onError : function(err) {
            alert('Whatever this method is doing got an error...');
            //I want to report the error here
    },
    onComplete : function() {
        // maybe do something else
    })
});
```

When I make a mistake (once in a blue moon) and the response to the AJAX request contains a stack trace. I want to put up a button that optionally renders the stack trace in another page.

In the onError method the err is undefined, so that is not helping. I do not see a property of the XSP object that would contain the response. I can see the response in the Firebug console, but how would I get it pragmatically?

/Newbs

Comment: Newbs, I have a big deadline this morning, but I'll try to give you an answer to this later today. :)

Comment: Tim, - not a problem. Sven stepped up and gave me the answer I needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the CSJS function *XSP*._*partialRefresh* checks if the *onError*-parameter is a function or not. if it is a function, it is called w/o the required parameters.

But if you use a string instead, a *eval* is done with it, so it would be possible to do something like this:

```
function myErrHandler(){
    // just do some debugging
    // of ioArgs object 
    var arg = arguments[1];
    var txt = "";
    for( p in arg ){
        txt += p + " -> " + arg[p] + " [" + typeof( arg[p] ) + "]\n";
    }
    alert( txt );
}

XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:newbsDoSomething}", {
    onError : 'myErrHandler( arguments[0], arguments[1] )'
});
```

Hope this helps

Sven

Comment: Sven: Very nice thanks. FWIW: The response HTML is in arguments[0].responseText.  So I used that to populate a new window so I can read the XPages error message.